# Efficient way of identifying request parameter

Tags: java, performance, servlets

There are 11 request parameters coming from client side to a servlet.  Once a request comes any one of them is set.  I need to identify which parameter is set. Is there an efficient way to identify the parameter set in client side?

Comment: This question is tagged java servlets.  Are you new to servlets?  Have you looked at `request.getParameter()`?

Comment: Can you clarify your questions?

Comment: no i'm not new to servlets i'm looking for a efficient way for iteration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cost calling `HttpServletRequest.getParameter(String)` on 11 possible parameters will be barely noticeable.  If it worries you though, call `HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap()` and iterate over the keys in the returned map.

Comment: There is no such method as `getParameters()`. You can find the right ones here: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

Comment: I guess what Stephen meant is **HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap()** and iterate over the map. Stop iterating the moment you get a non-null value.